# Improve the rendering of a JUNG graph 

Tags: java, jung

i am using jung to visually display large data sets, (1000s of nodes) but the system becomes very laggy when I zoom in or out, or move a node. Is there anyway to improve the rendering of graphs in JUNG ?

Answer (score 2):

The way that I used to improve rendering on graphs was to filter the edges of the graph. Every time you try to move the graph the framework do enormous calculations to reposition every vertex and edge and this causes bad performance.
The filtering could be done with adding AbstractPopupGraphMousePlugin succesor to the  DefaultModalGraphMouse object you are using. Simply override the handlePopup(MouseEvent mouseEvent).

Comment: Dimitar: Do you mean filtering to determine if the x and y coordinates of an edge's vertices are off screen?

Comment: Yes, you should dynamically calculated when the nodes are in the boundaries of the visible part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know specifically for graphs, but the usual options are

1. Only process what is actually shown on screen (zoom in)
2. Hide details when zooming out
3. Only update part of the screen that have actually changed content (move a node)